# $scope is not updated on camunda custom task form(Angular Js scope update)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, camunda

I have external camunda form loaded. $scope.exceptionObject is not updated once i modify/Edit my form. I am not sure why it is not happening.

```
camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {
  // fetch the variable named 'exceptionTemplate'
  camForm.variableManager.fetchVariable('exceptionTemplate');
});

camForm.on('variables-fetched', function() {
        // after the variables are fetched, bind the value to respective elements
    var exceptionTemplate = camForm.variableManager.variable('exceptionTemplate').value;
    console.log($.parseJSON(exceptionTemplate));
    $scope.exceptionObject = $.parseJSON(exceptionTemplate);
    console.log($scope.exceptionObject);
});
```

Expected Result :

`$scope.exceptionObject` should be updated with new value. `severity:"BLOCKER"` is not updated even if parsed json Object is already having updated value that is `severity:"NORMAL"`

[image]

I have tried to apply $scope.$apply(); for angular forums also but it is not helping. I am missing something, Why i am not able to update the scope variable ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: I couldn't understand the problem. the first log console.log($.parseJSON(exceptionTemplate)); so it logs the exceptionTemplate, then you assign it to property in the $scope and log it again. which seems it is updating the $scope ?? have I got  wrong ??

Comment: what are those event ? were you trying to use $on instead ? Are you using events that don't belong  to angularjs ? Please provide a fiddle to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Hussien yes i am trying to update $scope but it is not updating. You can see the log output for both are different.

Comment: @Gonzalo Can you share me sone example how to use $on ? This is related to camunda events. Example :https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/blob/master/usertask/task-form-embedded-serialized-java-object/src/main/webapp/forms/provide-customer-data.html